# How can I sort Fields, Properties and Methods in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I know that for clarity in codes, I have to write first fields then constructor and then methods etc. But how can I automate it in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you can look into StyleCop? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

Answer (score 79):

I think [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) is the best free option for code formatting in Visual Studio.

---

To sort your file, open the file via solution explorer:

1. Right click the open file
2. Code Maid menu (likely near the top of the right click menu)
3. Click `Reorganize Active Document`

Alternatively, using the default CodeMaid hotkeys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd> to sort your active file.

Comment: It didn't work as expected for me. It grouped properties with no reason, added spaces between some of them and removed the space between the comment and the property before that.

Comment: Visual Studio has a popup dialog that lets you manually reorder the parameters in a method when you change the method signature. I want that same manual functionality while reordering the members in a class. Does CodeMaid let you do that or does it just sort automatically?

Comment: According to the homepage of the project, it supports up to Visual Studio 2022. You can combine CodeMaid with the additional extension CM+ for even better formatting. I have tried it on some sample code, works just fine, and easy to use. Thank you!

Comment: I am wondering if CodeMaid could re-organize methods decorated with [Obsolete(...)] (group them together, move them to the end of the class etc)?

Answer (score 14):

ReSharper can sort your class members (fields, constructors, methods, delegates) by name, accessibility, type, readonly, etc... You can also surround specific members with regions. What I like the most is the ability to group interface members (e.g., `#region IDisposable` with `void Dispose()` method in it) and methods that handle an event.

ReSharper provides both - an easy way to configure and trigger the sorting of class members.

**Configuration**

Create a XML file within Visual Studio and copy-paste the default type member layout (ReSharper Options > Languages > C# > Type Members Layout) into that file. Download the latest [XSD schema](https://github.com/hhariri/Blog/tree/master/Various). Add the schema file to Visual Studio's schema files (Menu > XML > Schemas... > Add). You should be able now, to edit the XML file with the help of IntelliSense.

**Triggering**

If you use the *Visual Studio* keyboard scheme (ReSharper Options > Visual Studio Integration) and press <kbd>**Ctrl+E,F**</kbd> for *Silent Code Cleanup*. A dialog will pop up, where you can select a *Code Cleanup* setting. For this setting you should check *Reorder type members*. The second time you press the shortcut, ReSharper will automatically reorder your class members.

[1](https://github.com/hhariri/Blog/tree/master/Various): [ReSharper Type Members XSD Schema](https://github.com/hhariri/Blog/tree/master/Various)

Comment: Resharper is probably the most powerful extension ... but (understandably) it doesn't come for free.

Answer (score 8):

Limited sorting of lines is included with Visual Studio 2022.

To use: select the lines you want to sort and in the top menu click:
Edit > Advanced > Sort Lines

Comment: This will only sort lines, not functions. And it will order on whatever is the first letter of a line, not the method name, so not even much use for sorting Interfaces

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio has no feature that allows re-ordering already written code.  That's the domain of add-ons.  Resharper has a "Reordering type members" feature but that's only supported for C#, not for VB.NET code.  [NArrange](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318003026/http://narrange.net/) seems to be able to do this.  No idea, never used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Another option I found for Visual Studio 2010/2012 is [XArrange](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DoguTumerdem-outlook.XArrange2012). It is free and can be installed from the Extension Manager.

Issues I took with it...

0. It puts methods before constructors.
1. It removes any comments between members,properties,methods, etc.
2. It's configuration is very limited. No way to change sorting order.

   [image: XArrange Settings]

Comment: Written for Visual Studio 2012 and not updated since ...

Comment: I would never use a tool with "No, I hate" options.

Answer (score 1):

If code sorting in Visual Studio 2010-2013 is your only concern, you can try the Visual Studio Extension [CodeSorter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TehMarkos.CodeSorter)

> CodeSorter is highly customizable extension that allows its users to
> sort C# code itby various conditions such as names, types (method,
> class, struct, ...), visibility modifiers (private, public, ...),
> constness modifiers (const, static, readonly) and virtuality modifiers
> (virtual, override, new, ...).
>
> It is possible to assign multiple search criteria to have the same
> priority, for example place protected and private members first, and
> then publics and internals.
>
> Names are compared in a way that leading "m_" and "_" is stripped.
> This allows fields and properties (eg. _foo and Foo) to be right next
> to each other.
>
> One-lined declarations are placed without delimiting blank line, while
> multi-lined declarations are separated by a blank line. The exception
> is that one-lined field followed by a multi-lined property without
> comment of the same name will be placed without the delimiting blank
> line.

Comment: I looked at the project page of CodeSorter and the comments tell that unfortunately this tool is rather outdated, and it doesn't support Roslyn. Seems the developer doesn't want to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github Copilot chat to do this. I have found it works ok although on a large list of properties (90 - not my design!) it did leave out 1 and duplicate 1.

Comment: Interesting - could you describe in a bit more detail, how you did it? (For example, how the prompt looks like and which output format you chose)

Comment: I highlighted the list of properties, right clicked to select Copilot Chat and then asked Copilot to order them by name (not type) and accepted the answer.