# Hi, is there any way I can sort my code in Subs, such as in VB in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba

last year I did I class in VB at my school and at some point learnt a really useful way of sorting my code (through Private Sub / End Sub statements.) I've been starting to code in C# and was wondering if there is any way of doing this in C#

I would greatly appreciate and help, thanks.

Comment: `private void ...`? The [**MSDN Documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) provides great help for questions like this.

Comment: What do you mean with _sorting my code_ ?

Comment: @Steve : My guess: instead of having everything in for example one button click (or having to copy-paste it to many button clicks), split it up in methods which you can call at will.

Comment: By the way, Vadim, are you referring to VB.NET or VBA? Because they're not the same.

Comment: Looking at the linked post: No, there is no built-in way to keep mthods, function or any part od your code sorted or organized. Pity!

Comment: The linked post mentioned Resharper  by the  answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8599313/3142139, Really I did sorting using Resharper for methods, function by many criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

```
#region
//code code code
#endregion
```

by writing #region and #endregion, anything between the two can be folded down without changing anything regarding the functionality of the code.
you can event add a title to the folded area as such:

```
#region Math Functions

private int Add(int x, int y)
{
  // some code here
}

private int Sub(int x, int y)
{
  // some code here
}

private int Mult(int x, int y)
{
  // some code here
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Could you explain why this code answers the question?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanks Michael, that's what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks Vadim! down voted but still got the right answer :D